# How do I *avoid* passing arguments to function in Python pandas .apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, arguments, apply

I am wanting to experiment with the `raw=True` option in the pandas `apply` function, as per p. 155 in *High Performance Python,* by Gorelick and Ozsvald. However, Python is apparently regarding the `raw=True` as an argument for the function I'm applying, and not for the `.apply` function itself! Here's a MWE:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('a', 'b'))
df.loc[0] = (1, 2)
df.loc[1] = (3, 4)

df['a'] = df['a'].apply(str, raw=True)
```

When I try to execute this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'raw' is an invalid keyword argument for str()
```

The problem stays there even if I use a `lambda` expression:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: str(x), raw=True)
```

The problem remains if I call a custom-defined function instead of `str`.

**How do I get Pandas to recognize that `raw=True` is an argument for `.apply` and NOT `str`?**

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it is because you use `pd.Series.apply` and not `pd.DataFrame.apply`. Series doesn't seem to accept `raw` as argument. Try `df.apply(str, raw=True)`. Is that what you are searching for ?

Comment: @Rabinzel Hmm. I think you've got it. The examples in the book are definitely using the df version, not the ser version.

Comment: If you still only want to apply it to column a, use double brackets, that way you pass a dataframe instead of a Series: `df[['a']].apply(str, raw=True)`

Comment: That approach does have some side effects, though:

```
       a  b
0  [1 3]  2
1  [1 3]  4
```

Comment: You should really just do `df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str)`

Comment: @BeRT2me Well, except that this is a toy problem. I'm wanting to graduate from `str` to much more complicated examples.

Comment: Hmmk, well there's nothing to be gained from using `raw=True` with Series, because `pd.Series.apply` already passes raw values. `raw=True` is useful for `pd.DataFrame.apply` because it passes `numpy` arrays instead, which depending on your function can improve performance. As you can see in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply), there is no `raw=True` argument for a Series.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the comments, I don't think these are side effects. As in the documentation stated, passing `raw=True` as argument, the "function receive ndarray objects", so you pass an array and convert it to a string. The result is a string like `[1 3]`. So you don't convert each value to a string, instead the whole Series to a string

If you write a little helper function you can see that.

```
def conv(col):
    print(f"input values: {col}")
    print(f"type input: {type(col)}\n")
    return str(col)

t = df[['a']].apply(conv, raw=True)
print(f"{type(t)}:\n{t}\n")
print(f"first value: {type(t[0])}:\n{t[0]}\n")
print(f"{t[0][0]}")
```

Output:

```
input values: [1 3]
type input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>:
a    [1 3]
dtype: object

first value: <class 'str'>:
[1 3]

[
```

Comment: So if I want to convert a column to string from int using `apply` and `raw=True`, what is the exact syntax I should use?

Comment: My knowledge isn't deep enough to give advice here, but I think the answer is just: don't do it. The documentation also says "If you are just applying a NumPy reduction function this will achieve much better performance". You don't reduce anything here, so I don't think there is any advantage in using `raw`